# Sprinting, Jumping, and Main menu wont work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i'm a game designer working with c# and Unity (Just starting) and I have a main menu, sprint, and jump, but none of them will work. The jump was working until I made the main menu, and the sprint I just can't get to work.

```
const float walkSpeed = 6.0f;

  const float runSpeed = 11.0f;

  float moveSpeed = walkSpeed;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
      {
        Debug.Log("Run");
       // Set current speed to run if shift is down
       moveSpeed = runSpeed;
   }
   else {
       // Otherwise set current speed to walking speed
       moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
```

That's my run script and for some reason it wont work, I don't know why, seems like it should work.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
          velocityY = jumpSpeed;
        }

      if(controller.isGrounded)
        {
          velocityY = 0.0f;
        }
      velocityY += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
```

That's my jump/gravity stuff

```
  public void PlayGame ()
  {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
  }

  public void QuitGame ()
  {
    Debug.Log("Quit");
    Application.Quit();
  }
}
```

I don't see how the menu could be linked, but somehow after getting this in, the jump stopped working.

Comment: please be more specific on what "didn´t work" means. Do you get any error? Or does your app behave unexpectecdly? If so please post what you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: No, I don't get any errors, if I hit shift, it should sprint, it doesn't.

If i try to jump, it wont jump.

Comment: Well your code isnt viable enough to be helpful. As wothout knowing where some of that code is no one can properly answer

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to something like so for Run. I don't know if that's how it should work or if it's the best aproach, but i think it should work. Encapsulate it with ()

```
    if ( (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) ) && 
    Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) )
    {
        Debug.Log("Run");
        // Set current speed to run if shift is down
        moveSpeed = runSpeed;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise set current speed to walking speed
        moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
    }
```